Relation between spectral norm and Euclidean norm of a matrix in [BGG+'Eurocrypt2014]
I'm reading [BGG+'Eurocrypt2014]  paper and I doubt that maybe there be a typo in
relation between spectral norm and Euclidean norm of a matrix. Here is the part of the paper



I think we must have $\|\mathbf{R}\|_{2}\leq\sqrt{m}\|\mathbf{R}\|$, because according to the definition of the spectral norm, we must calculate the Euclidean norm of vector $\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_{i}\cdot\mathbf{r}_{i}$ (for some vector $\|\mathbf{x}\|=1$) where this vector is equal to linear combination of columns of matrix $\mathbf{R}$. The Euclidean norm of a matrix is the Euclidean norm of its largest columns. So $\|\mathbf{r}_{i}\|\leq\|\mathbf{R}\|$ for $i\in[m]$. Finally, we have $\|\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}\|\leq\sqrt{m}\|\mathbf{R}\|$.
When we want to know the upper bound of the Euclidean norm of a discrete Gaussian vector
like $\mathbf{e}\leftarrow\mathcal{D}_{\mathbb{Z}^{\ell},\sigma}$, Do we have $\|\mathbf{e}\|\leq\sigma\sqrt{\ell}$ as long as $\sigma\geq\omega(\sqrt{\log_{2}{\color{blue}\ell}})$ or as long as $\sigma\geq\omega(\sqrt{\log_{2}{\color{red}n}})$?

